# WebView - Detect when user clicks a link?

Tags: webview, navigation, windows-8, browser, windows-runtime

I have a WebView and I want to detect when the user clicks a link. However, there is no event that occurs when the user clicks a link. In Silverlight, WinForms, and WPF, there was the WebBrowser control with the Navigating event, but WinRT's WebView seems to be lacking many events. I cannot modify the web page as I am not the owner of it. Is there any way to detect when the user clicks a link?

In addition, the Source variable does not change when the user clicks a link, only when it is manually assigned to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to alter the source HTML for all links to call a custom `OnClick` script, and attach an event handler to the `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebView`

Comment: I have got this to work for me by modifying the source of the WebBrowser.

Comment: Link takes me to this same page :-(